# Difference between passing 2d arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
char** fun1(char **arr, int x, int y) 
{/*THE SAME CODE IN EACH FUNCTION */};
char** fun2(*arr[], int x, int y);
{/*THE SAME CODE IN EACH FUNCTION */};
char** fun3(arr[][], int x, int y);
{/*THE SAME CODE IN EACH FUNCTION */};
char** fun4(arr[][10], int x, int y);
{/*THE SAME CODE IN EACH FUNCTION */};

int main()
{
    int arr[5][10]
    char** x,y,z,v;

    x=fun1(arr,5,10);
    y=fun2(arr,5,10);
    z=fun3(arr,5,10);
    v=fun4(arr,5,10);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any difference between those functions? Particularly I need to know if fun4 differs from others in any little detail.

Comment: `fun3()` won't compile.  It isn't clear what `x` and `y` are used for in the functions — are they the size of the array?  You can't call `fun1` or `fun2` with `arr` as defined in `main()`, either.  So the little detail related to `fun4()` is "it would probably work" whereas none of the others would.

Comment: None of 2 through 4 will compile; did you forget the `char` in the type of the first parameter? And you're passing two-dimensional array of `int` to a function expecting a two-dimensional array of `char` for the first option.

Comment: Try compiling your code and seeing what the compiler has to say ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put `char` at the start of each of those parameters so they parse at all, here's what they mean:

- `fun1` has `char **arr` as the first parameter. This is read as "`arr` is a pointer to pointer to `char`". The type you're trying to pass in is an array of *arrays*, not an array of *pointers*, so it won't work correctly here; array-to-pointer decay doesn't work except at the top level of a type.
- `fun2` has `char *arr[]` as the first parameter. This is read as "`arr` is an array of indeterminate length of pointers to `char`". Here, the first part is "`arr` is an array", so array-to-pointer decay works and this is equivalent to `fun1` (and again it won't work).
- `fun3` has `char arr[][]` as the first parameter. This is read as "`arr` is an array of indeterminate length of arrays of indeterminate length of `char`s". You cannot store arrays of indeterminate length in arrays (because you can't know what their size is at compile time), so it fails to compile right then.
- Finally, `fun4` has `char arr[][10]` as the first parameter. This is read as "`arr` is an array of indeterminate length of arrays of ten `char`s". With array-to-pointer decay, this is equivalent to `char (*arr)[10]`, "`arr` is a pointer to array of ten `char`s". This is different from the others, since it expects the array to contain fixed-size arrays instead of pointers. This would match what you pass in, except you use `int` to declare it in `main`, and `int` is not equivalent to `char`.

Example you don't list are `char *arr[5]`, `char arr[5][]`, or `char arr[5][10]`. These are read as "`arr` is an array of five...`, and from array-to-pointer decay are equivalent to cases 2, 3, and 4, respectively; in particular, the compiler doesn't verify that it really is a five-element-long array.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote wrong code. I  meant it to be 'char arr[5][10]' not int